# git - get rid of unreachable commit

Tags: git

I am trying to cleanup my repository and remove everything unreachable.

I did

```
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git fsck --full --unreachable
git repack -A -d
git gc --aggressive --prune=now
```

But I still have some commits that are unreachable from my understanding but not by git's

I have some commit, let's say A

```
git branch --all --contains A
git tag --contains A
```

return nothing

but

```
git fsck --full --unreachable
```

also returns nothing so it does not consider A as an unreachable.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, I found it!

That is **refs/original/mybranch** ref that still keep my commit reachable.

These **original** refs are created during **git filter-branch**

```
git branch --all
```

does not include them.

The reason why I did not find them at the beginning because they were missing in **.git/refs/original** folder.

I found them in **.git/packed-refs** file. I just removed those branches from that file and cleaned repository again.